# removing duplicates from a ruby array without using built in methods... eg. .uniq, .sort etc

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, duplicates

Im struggling trying to remove some duplicates from an array. I have a spec which requires I do not not use inbuilt sorting & de-duplication methods...
so `.uniq` `.sort` etc. Are out of use...

Here is my array ...

```
array = [1, "fred", 6, 5, "fred", "john", 6, "peter", "fred"]
```

I need it to output...

```
sorted_array = [1, 6, 5, "fred", "john", "peter"]
```

So far I have tried to use a `Set` as well as  `array & array` however that outputs in the wrong order. I need the integers to occur in the list before the strings...

I have also tried to iterate through, finding if an element occurs more than once and using .delete & .delete_at however I can't figure out how to delete the second/third/fourth occurring element...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which built-in methods you can't use, but if you can use [Array#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C) it's hard to imagine anything simpler than

```
array | []
  #=> [1, "fred", 6, 5, "john", "peter"]
```

Note this retains the ordering of `array`.

`array & array` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Creating and returning a secondary cleaned array makes this fairly simple: iterate over the original array and append only those elements that do not already exist within the cleaned array:

```
def clean(array)
  cleaned = []
  array.each do |element|
    cleaned << element  if not cleaned.include?(element)
  end
  return cleaned
end
```

This is relatively quick and does exactly what you want.

*Proof of concept (irb):*

```
2.2.2 :001 > def clean(array); cleaned=[];  array.each{|ele| cleaned << ele  if not cleaned.include? ele}; cleaned; end
 => :clean

2.2.2 :002 > clean [1, "fred", 6, 5, "fred", "john", 6, "peter", "fred"]
 => [1, "fred", 6, 5, "john", "peter"]
```

You could improve processing times on large arrays by using a `Hash` instead.  This would work by appending elements as keys to improve the internal lookup times, and then simply return a list of its keys for your array.  (Caveat: doing this may return them in an arbitrary order, however, so further effort may be required to maintain the original order.)

**Edit:** I missed the sorting requirement in your expected output.  Apologies.

Comment: No worries! :) I had this same method at one point! It's always the sorting that catches me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @terra did:

```
def uniq(array)
  uniq = []
  array.each do |element|
    uniq << element unless uniq.include?(element)
  end
  uniq
end

def sort(array)
  sorted = []
  [Integer, String].each do |type|
    sorted += array.select { |element| element.is_a? type }
  end
  sorted
end
```

So now if you do this:

```
p uniq_and_sorted = sort(uniq([1, "fred", 6, 5, "fred", "john", 6, "peter", "fred"]))
```

You should get:

```
[1, 6, 5, "fred", "john", "peter"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe long winded, but it works:

```
    array = [1, "fred", 6, 5, "fred", "john", 6, "peter", "fred"]

    numbers_array = []
    array.each do |e|
      numbers_array << e if e == e.to_i
    end

    numbers_array.sort!

    strings_array = []
    array.each do |e|
        strings_array << e if e == e.to_s
    end

    strings_array.sort!

    final_array = []
    final_array << numbers_array << strings_array
    final_array.flatten!
    final_array.uniq!

    p final_array
```